# Knockout binding for Bootstrap toggle buttons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, durandal, knockout-2.0

I'm looking for a way in KnockoutJS to bind toggle button to a function that gets called when a specific value (button) is selected.

I tried several solutions and got it running with just KnockoutJS, but when I add Boostrap to it, it still doesn't work.

My code shown here does not trigger the handler function associated with `checked` event. For the latest working example, use the JSFiddle.

HTML:

```
<div id="access-rights-control" class="btn-group pull-right" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-xs">
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="1" id="status-published" data-bind="checked: $root.allowAccessHandler" />Allow access
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-xs active">
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="0" id="status-draft" checked /> No change
  </label>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var viewModel = function() {
  this.allowAccessHandler = function() {
    alert("Works!");
  }
};
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/p8nSe/191/

Comment: That's not how the `checked` binding works

Comment: Updated the question, I did it because the solution for KnockoutJS doesn't work when I add Bootstrap to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found an approach that works natively and gets the task done. I'm not sure if it is the most generic one, since I have to override `ko.bindingHandlers.radio`, but it works.

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.radio = {
      init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, data, context) {
        var $buttons, $element, observable;
        observable = valueAccessor();
        if (!ko.isWriteableObservable(observable)) {
          throw "You must pass an observable or writeable computed";
        }
        $element = $(element);
        if ($element.hasClass("btn")) {
          $buttons = $element;
        } else {
          $buttons = $(".btn", $element);
        }
        elementBindings = allBindings();
        $buttons.each(function() {
          var $btn, btn, radioValue;
          btn = this;
          $btn = $(btn);
          radioValue = elementBindings.radioValue || $btn.attr("data-value") || $btn.attr("value") || $btn.text();
          $btn.on("click", function() {
            observable(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(radioValue));
          });
          return ko.computed({
            disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved: btn,
            read: function() {
              $btn.toggleClass("active", observable() === ko.utils.unwrapObservable(radioValue));
            }
          });
        });
      }
    };

    var viewModel = function() {
      this.radioSelected = ko.observable('0');
      this.radioSelected.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        console.debug("Comparing", newValue, '1');
        if (newValue === '1') {
          alert("Works!");
        }
      });
    };
    ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn" data-bind="radio: radioSelected, radioValue: '1'">Allow access</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" data-bind="radio: radioSelected, radioValue: '0'">No change</button>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p8nSe/192/

Answer (score 4):

Maybe what you want is something like what the snippet below do. please see and gimme a feedback.

```js
ko.bindingHandlers["bsChecked"]  ={
  init: function(element, valueAccessor){
    ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element,"change",function(event){
        var check = $(event.target);
        valueAccessor()(check.val());      
    });
  }
 
};

var viewModel = function() {
  
  this.checkedButton = ko.observable("2").extend({ notify: 'always' });
  
  this.checkedButton.subscribe( function(checkedVal) {
    // here you can decide what to do depends on the new checkedVal
    alert("Works! : "+ checkedVal);
  },this); 
  
};
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div id="access-rights-control" class="btn-group pull-left" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-xs btn-default">
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="1" data-bind="bsChecked: checkedButton" />Allow access
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-xs btn-default">
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="2" data-bind="bsChecked: checkedButton" />No change
  </label>
</div>
```

### Update

> Created a binding handler to take care about the prevent changes caused by bootstrap, so this is a workaround and I suggest to you read about [KO custom bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) and implement the `update` function of the binding handler.

Comment: While it works with KnockoutJS, it doesn't work with added Bootstrap. I think that was my problem from the beginning.. You can check the updated JSFiddle.

Comment: @PeterGerhat see the snippet now, i do it using bind handler as workaround about the events prevent of the bootstrap. So you just need to do some validations about the elements type that the bind handler accepts and all it's good.

Comment: this looks good, if you could make it set the initial state set in `ko.observable("2")` this would be the solution

Answer (score 1):

If you want something to run when you click on the `input`, then you need to use an [event](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html) binding not the [checked](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html) binding (which just binds the checked state to an observable, it's not an event handler). Something like:

```js
var viewModel = function() {
  this.allowAccessHandler = function() {
    alert("Works!");
  }
};
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div id="access-rights-control" class="btn-group pull-right" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-xs">
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="1" id="status-published" data-bind="event: { change: $root.allowAccessHandler }" />Allow access
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-xs active">
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="0" id="status-draft" /> No change
  </label>
</div>
```

Now if you have the `checked` state bound to a property in your view model, it would probably be better to just `subscribe` to that property instead of attaching an event handler to the DOM as that would be more inline with separating your view and view model.

Comment: I dont think so, one of the purpose of the KO JS, is abstract the direct DOM manipulation.

Comment: @JoelRamosMichaliszen: I already had a note at the bottom on exactly that. But this answers the question that the OP asked and shows them how to attach an event handler other than `click` which they were clearly confused by.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two issues:

1. You don't have a binding handler for the Bootstrap radio group, which means that your `checked` binding isn't going to work
2. You aren't using the `checked` binding correctly.

I can help you with the 2nd. In a radio group where all the elements have the same `name` attribute and different `value` attributes, the variable bound to the `checked` observable will get the value of the selected radio item.

You can subscribe to the observable and take action when it gets a particular value.

```js
var viewModel = function() {
  this.radioSelected = ko.observable();
  this.radioSelected.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    console.debug("Comparing", newValue, '1');
    if (newValue === '1') {
      alert("Works!");
    }
  });
  this.radioSelected('0');
  this.output = ko.observableArray();
};
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div id="access-rights-control" class="btn-group pull-right" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-xs btn-default">
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="1" data-bind="checked: radioSelected" />Allow access
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-xs btn-default active">
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="0" data-bind="checked: radioSelected" />No change
  </label>
</div>
<div data-bind="foreach:output">
  <div data-bind="text:$data">
  </div>
</div>
```

Again, this won't work if you have Bootstrap-styled radio buttons, because Bootstrap fiddles with the DOM in ways that Knockout isn't set up to detect. So you need [a binding handler that works with Bootstrap radio magic](https://faulknercs.github.io/Knockstrap/#buttons). That may require that your approach be slightly different (ie, you may not use the `checked` binding) I don't know.

Comment: Your example works with KnockoutJS, but it doesn't when I add Bootstrap to it. Perhaps you can have a second look at it, I updated the JSFiddle for you.

Comment: @PeterGerhat You should read what I wrote, in addition to looking at the example.

Comment: The solution for Bootstrap just doesn't work when I use it under KnockoutJS. In my answer I provided a workaround where the `radio` binding is defined and well once it's defined.